# How to parse nested array values from json and show it in listview template nativescript angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-template, nativescript-angular

- In below json structure if you see `marks array`. I have to get and
  show the mark array body value : first, second and third.
- These first, second and third values placed inside marks Array. I
  don't know how to fetch this value and show it in listview template.
- I just want to show all the three values in every listview item
  position

**students.json:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "denver",
        "marks": [
            {
                "identity": [],
                "body": {
                    "first": "Pollard",
                    "second": "Bravo",
                    "third": "Kevin"
                } 
            },
            {
                "identity": [],
                "body": {
                    "first": "Michael",
                    "second": "Waugh",
                    "third": "Stone"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "kallis",
        "marks": [
            {
                "identity": [],
                "body": {
                    "first": "Yuvi",
                    "second": "Maxwell",
                    "third": "Rock"
                }
            },
            {
                "identity": [],
                "body": {
                    "first": "Steve",
                    "second": "Laughlin",
                    "third": "Jeff"
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "younis",
        "marks": [
            {
                "identity": [],
                "body": {
                    "first": "Ben",
                    "second": "Stokes",
                    "third": "Smith"
                }
            },
            {
                "identity": [],
                "body": {
                    "first": "Archer",
                    "second": "Matt",
                    "third": "Glenn"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<StackLayout height="100%">

    <ListView [items]="studentList" class="list-group" height="70%">
        <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
            <StackLayout class="input-border">

                <Label [text]="item.name" class="module-title"></Label>

             <!--   <StackLayout>
                    <Label [text]="item.first" class="user-title"></Label>
                    <Label [text]="item.second" class="item-title" textWrap="true"></Label>
                    <Label [text]="item.third" class="item-title" textWrap="true"></Label>

                </StackLayout>  -->

            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>

    </ListView>
```

App.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ObservableArray } from 'data/observable-array'
import { Student } from './model/Student';
import * as Application from "application";
import { AppService } from './app.service'

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    moduleId: module.id,
    providers: [AppService],
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private studentList: ObservableArray<Student>;

    constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.studentList = this.appService.getStudent();
    }

}
```

**app.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Student } from './model/Student'
import { ObservableArray } from 'data/observable-array'

var getData = require("./model/student.json");

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    getStudent(): ObservableArray<Student> {
        var studentList: ObservableArray<Student> = new ObservableArray<Student>();

        console.log("StudentArray", JSON.stringify(getData));

        for (var i = 0; i <getData.length; i++) {
            var student = new Student();
            student.name = getData[i].name;
            console.log("nameStudent", getData[i].name);


        studentList.push(student);

        }

        return studentList;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `marks` is an array of Objects, you should be able to access these values via array access followed by field access:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label [text]="item.marks[0].body.first" class="user-title"></Label>
    <Label [text]="item.marks[0].body.second" class="item-title" textWrap="true"></Label>
    <Label [text]="item.marks[0].body.third" class="item-title" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

But if you want to show *all* marks without manually specifying an index for `marks`, you'll need one more for loop.

Comment: we cant sure how many messages we will be getting in services. it may be two or three or four, etc.. so i'm looking for dynamic way of marks[i]. But its overlapping the label one after another. Not able to use two listview in single template

Comment: Just make it a for loop then. `*ngFor="let obj of item.marks"` then within the for loop add labels using `<Label [text]=obj.body.first ....`